# How to prevent Next.js from removing new lines from paragraphs in the HTML document that it generates?

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I have the following code in my `page.tsx` file:

```
<p className="whitespace-pre-wrap">
First line text

Third line text
</p>
```

Next.js puts this into the HTML document that it generates:

```
First line text Third line text
```

I want it to like this in the HTML document:

```
First line text

Third line text
```

WITHOUT having to use the HTML 
 element.

How can this be achieved in Next.js?

I'm using Next.js version 14.1.0

Comment: The tailwind [class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/whitespace#pre-wrap) you have set should be working. Can you inspect element to see if the class has applied?

Comment: @aabdulahad The Tailwind CSS class works if I don't use Next.js and instead create a static HTML document on the file system and then open it in a browser.

Comment: Not to doubt you but have you done the following?  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Comment: @aabdulahad Valid question, I didn't state this in my question. I have the Tailwind npm package installed and it works for other Tailwind classes. In my package.json file: `"tailwindcss": "^3.3.0"` - also all other Tailwind CSS classes like flex, mt-2,... are working as intended.

Comment: How you're trying to manage line breaks is extremely fragile since there are so many things that can break it like prettier, formatters, compliers, different code editor settings etc. For consistency, it's standard practice to use multiple block elements like `<p>`, insert `<br/>` for manual line breaks, or `\n` in JS for breaks. For preserving spaces and breaks, style an element that uses the output of a `textarea` with `white-space: pre-wrap;` or use the output of a rich text editor like Tiptap.

Comment: @SeanW standard practice according to who? Twitter/X is using `whitespace-pre-wrap` for user's posts/tweets which is where I got the idea from.

Comment: Yes - but it uses the output from a rich text editor. You can do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this in a NextJS sandbox, try using a template literal to preserve the whitespace when the code is transpiled:

```js
<p className="whitespace-pre-wrap">
{`First line text 
      
Third line text`}
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. This has worked for me as intended. Case solved. :)